# Is there a way to enter debugger when running executable?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

We have a rather large program that consumes messages from a remote server. The program is now fairly stable, but every month or so of continuous run time it runs into trouble. Examples is entering an eternal loop, problem with files being locked and such. We've spent a great deal of time trying to figure out what causes the problems, but can't figure it out. Is there any way we can jump into debug mode when the executable is running? We would prefer not having to keep the program running in debug mode in VS as this impacts performance and eats tons of memory after a while.

Comment: Here's a starting point: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/vstudio/ff678494(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Have you tried profiling the application? You don't say what version of VS you are using but there are both in-built and external tools that can  monitor and profile your running production app.

Comment: There are many things you can do before trying to attach a debugger. For example, you can take a hang dump using [ProcDump](http://blogs.technet.com/b/kristinw/archive/2012/10/03/procdump-how-to-properly-gather-dump-dmp-files-for-crashes-and-hangs.aspx) or [DebugDiag](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chaun/archive/2014/02/17/three-ways-to-automate-a-hang-dump-in-debugdiag-2-0.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Debugger.Launch()

Comment: Thanks, we simply added a button that triggers debugger.launch on the GUI. Thanks a lot for the tip :)